# SQL joins in MS SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables, EPISODES and PRESENTERS

```
EPISODES
EPI_NO   PRES_ID
1        001
2        002
3        001

PRESENTERS
PRES_ID         FNAME      SNAME
001             Tom        Smith
002             Steve      Harris
```

I want to write a query that finds the Presenter who has done the most number of episodes and display his FNAME and SNAME is this format:

Tom              Smith                         2

```
Select Top 1 PRES_ID,count(*) as NumberOfEpisodes From 
EPISODES    
Group By PRES_ID
Order By NumberOfEpisodes DESC
```

I have managed to make this query that finds the Presenter that has done the most number of episodes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Now `JOIN` it with other table to get rest data like

```
select p.FNAME + ' ' + p.SNAME as Name,
xxx.NumberOfEpisodes
FROM PRESENTERS p
JOIN ( Select Top 1 PRES_ID,
       count(*) as NumberOfEpisodes 
       From EPISODES    
       Group By PRES_ID ) xxx ON p.PRES_ID = xxx.PRES_ID;
```